# python error when insert data

Tags: python, odoo

table x_giolam:

```
class x_giolam(osv.osv):
    _name = 'x_giolam'
    _description = 'Gio Lam'
    _columns = {
                        'name': fields.integer('Lọai',size=64,required="true"),
                        'giolam' : fields.float('Gio lam',size=64,required="True"),
                        'time_in': fields.char('Gio vào',size=20),
                        'time_out' :fields.char('Gio về',size=20),

    }   
x_giolam()
```

table x_luong:

```
class x_luong(osv.osv):
        _name = 'x_luong'
        _description = 'Luong'     
    _columns = {

                    'name': fields.many2one('x_nhanvien','Mã nhân viên',size=10,required='1'),
                    'ma_luong': fields.integer('ma luong',size=10,required='1'),
                    'giolam': fields.float('Giờ làm',size=100,required='1'),
                    'giolamthuc': fields.char('Gio lam thuc te',size=5,required='1'),
                'time_in': fields.char('Gio vào',size=20),
                'time_out' :fields.char('Gio về',size=20),
                'state' :fields.selection([('dangnhap','Đẳng nhập.'),('rave','Ra về')]),
                'test': fields.integer('Kiem tra',size=20),
                'phutvao': fields.integer('Phut vao ',size=20),
                'phutra': fields.integer('phut ra',size=20),
        }
```

function insert();

```
def insert(self,cr,uid,ids,context={}):
                obj=self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)
                values={'name':obj.ma_luong.id,
                        'giolam':obj.giolam,
                        'time_in':obj.time_in,
                        'time_out':obj.time_out,
                        }
                self.pool.get('x_giolam').create(cr,uid,values,context=context)
```

and last this is error:

```
AttributeError: 'browse_record_list' object has no attribute 'ma_luong'
```

i do it in openerp
and self of function in x_luong

i want insert to table x_giolam some attribute but have this error . Help me please thanks!!!

Comment: can i help me........... please?

Comment: What database do you use? What `browse` method does? And what is the `self`?

Comment: please be more precise when asking questions

Comment: who know about openerp.. help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that some how the `self.browse()` method returns the `obj` that have no `ma_luong` property.

I suggest to put some debug output after `obj=…` before `values=…` eg `print dir(obj)`.

Comment: i do it in open erp ... i can't print and test it

Comment: @ThongTran well then your problem cannot be solved. I suggest to address your question to the OpenERP developers or their support team.